# activity is getting destroyed on permission dialog appearing on fragment

Tags: android-fragments, runtime-permissions

Hosting Activity is getting destroyed as soon as permission dialog is appearing on fragment.

On click of Submit button of fragment:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please allow permission so we can retrieve the OTP.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 441);

            }
```

I tried with `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` still hosting activity is getting destroyed and showing permission dialog only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this line from AndroidManifest for that activity:

> android:noHistory="true"

solved issue.